# Why doesn't the MoneyFormat script variable work?

Tags: qliksense

The script variable [`MoneyFormat`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/NumberInterpretationVariables/MoneyFormat.htm) is supposed to control the default format used for the [`Money`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Money.htm) function.  It doesn't seem to work.  Why is that?

```cs
Set MoneyFormat = '$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00';

...

LOAD
    Money(Revenue, '$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00') AS Revenue1,  // OK:   $123,456.78
    Money(Revenue, '$(MoneyFormat)') AS Revenue2,        // OK:   $123,456.78
    Money(Revenue) AS Revenue3,                          // Wrong: $123456.78
    ...
```

**Edit:**

I don't know how much of this is relevant, but to be clear, here are all of my settings instead of just `MoneyFormat`:

```
SET ThousandSep=',';
SET DecimalSep='.';
SET MoneyThousandSep=',';
SET MoneyDecimalSep='.';
SET MoneyFormat='$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00';
SET TimeFormat='h:mm:ss TT';
SET DateFormat='M/D/YYYY';
SET TimestampFormat='M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss[.fff] TT';
SET FirstWeekDay=6;
SET BrokenWeeks=1;
SET ReferenceDay=0;
SET FirstMonthOfYear=1;
SET CollationLocale='en-US';
SET CreateSearchIndexOnReload=1;
SET MonthNames='Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec';
SET LongMonthNames='January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December';
SET DayNames='Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat;Sun';
SET LongDayNames='Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday;Sunday';
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Doesn't work after all.... See comments

This looked like a simple problem, but it took me quite a while to actually solve it since the documentation doesn't really help at all.

The solution should be:

Replace this:

```
Set MoneyFormat = '$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00';
```

with this:

```
Set MoneyDecimalSep='.';
Set MoneyThousandSep=',';
Set MoneyFormat='$ #,##0.00;$ -#,##0.00';
```

So in the end it's quite simple. I solved it by looking at the variable MoneyFormat and after a while I noticed the important difference between $ and € numbers and this took me to the missing variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, my script already contains `MoneyDecimalSep` and `MoneyThousandSep` (see my edit).  But for you, it didn't work without those and then it started working once you added them?  I also see your `MoneyFormat` is a little different than mine, but I assume that's just incidental?

Comment: I have tried recreating my example, but I can't. It seems I got confused with one of my other variables. I was probably happy I finally found the answer. I'll take a look again tomorrow, sorry for the false hope.

Comment: Oh, ok.  No worries.  Thanks.